# MySQL Query Behaviour on v5.7

Tags: mysql

We have two MySQL Database system.

> 1. with Version 5.7.32
> 2. With Version 5.7.35

Below query is executing on Server #1 but not on Server #2, however it was running fine on both till yesterday.

Query being used :

```
select A, 
       B, 
       SUM(C)
from TableX
group by A;
```

Now from today onwards, we had to change the query as below to run on Server #2 :

```
select A, 
       B, 
       SUM(C)
from TableX
group by A,B;
```

Please suggest.

Comment: What have you changed _since yesterday_? Do you get any errors _or_ better describe "not running on Server #2"?  Compare all parameters.

Comment: Check `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL Mode - it is set on the server where the query fails (on Server #2).

Comment: *we had to change the query as below to run on Server #2* If `A` column is not set as UNIQUE (maybe primary key) then this query logic is not the same, and it will produce the output which differs from those of 1st query.

Comment: Nothing has changed from Yesterday. @Akina Thanks a lot !! Indeed the SQL_MODE was set to ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY on server #2, what we don't understand is how it became active on its own, till yesterday, same query was running fine on both server.